# AXI bus to Wishbone Wrapper

Tags: vhdl, xilinx-ise, amba

Could anyone please tell me about the AXI bus and its signals. I would also want to know about AXI bus to wishbone bus wrapper to implement it in VHDL. 
I am looking at the implementation of a register in FPGA and then give the corresponding commands from LINUX to drive the LED's on a zedboard. wishbone bus is used to transfer the data and make communication with the register.

Comment: Have you tried googling? See [AXI Reference Guide](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/ip_documentation/axi_ref_guide/v13_4/ug761_axi_reference_guide.pdf) from Xilinx for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some documents for the AMBA (Advanced Microcontroller Bus Architecture) including AXI and AXI-Light:

- [Xilinx UG761 - AXI Reference Guide](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/ip_documentation/axi_ref_guide/v13_4/ug761_axi_reference_guide.pdf)
- [ARM - AMBA Open Specifications](http://www.arm.com/products/system-ip/amba/amba-open-specifications.php)
- [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Microcontroller_Bus_Architecture)

If you are going to write a GPIO to register mapping module for WishBone, why don't you write a AXI to register / GPIO mapper and spare the AXI2WB bridge?

I thought [OpenCores](http://www.http://opencores.org/) has a AXI2WB wrapper, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

I know, that this is an old question, but as there is no answer providing link to the right HDL source, I'd like to propose a few:

1. There is an [AXI to WB bridge](https://bitbucket.org/danstrother/dls_cores/src/beb677ea1919ea2cec984426e1f8d89ec21b03a7/axi/rtl/dlsc_axi_to_wb.v?at=default) written in Verilog by Daniel Strother (it was written in 2011)
2. On [OpenCores](http://opencores.org/project,ax4lbr) there is a very simple AXI4-Lite to Wishbone bridge (the project contains also AXI4-Lite to IPbus bridge) written in VHDL by me and my colleague.